# When using Serilog with ASP.NET Core 3.0 how do I create a logger on the fly with separate configuration than the root logger?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have a Windows service that I am writing using .Net Core 3.0. My service needs to have logging for both a service and jobs that are processed within that service. I'd like the service to log to the console (when applicable) and a log file. This is easy enough:

```
var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(this.ConfigurationRoot, "Logging")
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: LogMessageFormat, theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate);


if (this.AppConfiguration.Value.CreateLogFile)
{
     var filePath = Path.Combine(this.AppConfiguration.Value.LogFilePath, "service.log");
      loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.File(filePath, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose, outputTemplate: LogMessageFormat);
}

// Now every ILogger or ILogger<T> that I resolve uses the above configuration
Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger();
```

However, this service processes jobs from a queue and each job needs to have it's processing logged to a file that only includes the logs from the processing. Any logging that the job does must show up in a *separate* log file and when the processing of the job is complete the file never gets modified again.

For example, suppose the service is running and then a job comes in. I'd like to have the service logging output:

```
service.log
Service is waiting...
Service is waiting...
Service is waiting...
Service is waiting...
Starting job 1234
Completed job 1234
Service is waiting...
Service is waiting...
Starting job 5678
Completed job 5678
Service is waiting...
...
```

and then the process specific logs

```
service.process1234.log
This log message is logged by the handler for process 1234
```

```
service.process5678.log
This log message is logged by the handler for process 5678
```

It would be really convenient if I could somehow use the `ILoggerFactory` to create a logger with configuration ***that was separate from the root logger*** when I created the class that does the processing. For example:

```
public class ProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;

    public ProcessorFactory(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        this.loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public IProcessor CreateProcessor(JobRequest request)
    {
        // Something like this is what I'm hoping to be able to do
        var loggingConfig = new LoggingConfig { File = $"service.process{request.Id}" };
        var processLogger = this.loggerFactory.CreateLogger(...);
        var processor = new Processor(processLogger, request);
        return processor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a non-file based approach for your logs instead? Using a sink like [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) for your logs can make it very easy to filter down to show output from a single job.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. Unfortunately having a log file is a requirement. I suppose I could write the logs to a DB or some other source and when a user wants to download the log file I could read the logs from the DB and create the file at that point.

Comment: Is there any issue you create a new `LoggerConfiguration` and `loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger()` in `CreateProcessor`? Something like `            var createLog = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                                .WriteTo.Console()
                                .WriteTo.File("Create.log")
                                .CreateLogger();
            createLog.Information("Info From Create");
`